# Number of nested objects in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Looking for a way to get the number of nested objects, for querying, sorting etc.
For example, given this index:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "some_id": {"type": "long"},
      "user": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "first": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "last": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "some_id": 111,
  "user" : [
    {
      "first" : "John",
      "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "last" :  "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to filter by the number of users (e.g. query fetching all documents with more than XX users).

I was thinking to using a runtime_field but this gives an error:

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "num": {
      "type": "long",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit(doc['some_id'].value)"
      }
    },
    "num1": {
      "type": "long",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit(doc['user'].size())" // <- this breaks with "No field found for [user] in mapping"
      }
    }
  }
  ,"fields": [
    "num","num1"
  ]
}
```

Is it possible perhaps using aggregations?

Would also be nice to know if I can sort the results (e.g. all documents with more than XX and sorted desc by XX).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query this *efficiently*

It is possible to use this hack for it, but I would only do it if you need to do some one-time fetching, not for a regular use case as it uses `params._source` and is therefore really slow when you have a lot of docs

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "min_score": 1,  # -> min number of nested docs to filter by
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "params._source['user'].size()"
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

It basically calculates a new score for each doc, where the score is equal to the length of the users array, and then removes all docs under `min_score` from returning

Comment: Yes this is designated for a one-time fetch. Thanks.

Comment: btw i am wondering why is it not possible to use runtime fields for this? not sure why '.size()' is available for params._source but not for the 'doc'. Is it because the context of 'doc' is just the current document without the nested documents and params_.source provides both the original document and the nested documents?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to add a `userCount` field at indexing time (since you know how many elements there are) and then query that field using a `range` query. Very simple, efficient and fast.

Each element of the nested array is a document in itself, and thus, not queryable via the root-level document.

If you cannot re-create your index, you can leverage the `_update_by_query` endpoint in order to add that field:

```
POST my-index-000001/_update_by_query?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
     ctx._source.userCount = ctx._source.user.size()
    """
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val. However I am trying to avoid updating a huge amount of documents. This is also designated for some one-time querying of the current data.

Comment: If you have a huge amount of documents, then the scripting approach is not really going to perform really well (because the script will have to be evaluated against ALL documents before the query can return)... But if it's just a one-time why not... Just know for next time, that this the best practice is to compute this at indexing time.